# Reflection Exception in laravel vanilo.io

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, e-commerce, vanilo

Everything was working fine until I added Vanilo to my laravel project, I have no idea on how to debug this kindly help.

**Laravel Version:** 5.5.40

[image: Reflection Error]

**Snippet from app.php**

```
/*
     * Third Party Aliases
     */
    'Active'      => HieuLe\Active\Facades\Active::class,
    'Breadcrumbs' => DaveJamesMiller\Breadcrumbs\Facade::class,
    'Captcha'     => Arcanedev\NoCaptcha\Facades\NoCaptcha::class,
    'Form'        => Collective\Html\FormFacade::class,
    'Fractal' => Spatie\Fractal\FractalFacade::class,
    'Gravatar'    => Creativeorange\Gravatar\Facades\Gravatar::class,
    'Html'        => Collective\Html\HtmlFacade::class,
    'Socialite'   => Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite::class,
    'Image' => Intervention\Image\Facades\Image::class,
    'Helper' => App\Helpers\Helper::class,
    'Agent' => Jenssegers\Agent\Facades\Agent::class,
    'Concord' => Konekt\Concord\Facades\Concord::class,
    'Helper'  => Konekt\Concord\Facades\Helper::class,
```

even if remove the last helper i still get the error.

Comment: are you using any helper as shown in error

Comment: ok i have see vanilo has a helper so there are 2 helpers. i have updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hit these commands

```php
php artisan config:clear
composer dump-autoload
```